# Preserve pitch on html video element (preservesPitch, mozPreservesPitch, webkitPreservesPitch)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-video, pitch

I'm trying to disable preservesPitch feature on video element that plays slow motion through modifying video.playbackRate

On chrome video.webkitPreservesPitch is undefined, and if I set to false or true there is no difference in sound.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement says "this API has not been standarized"

Do you know any way to disable preservesPitch feature on browsers?
Thank you.

Comment: As of **Chrome 86**, you can use the [preservesPitch](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5742134990733312) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can disable the pitch preservation feature with

```
var el=document.getElementById('videoid')
el.mozPreservesPitch = false; //Firefox
el.preservesPitch = false; //Chrome
```

Default value is true.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).